# Error when trying to update Enterprise Architect StateMachine Connector in Jscript

Tags: enterprise-architect

When Updating a Enterprise Architect connector i get the following Error Message:

```
StateFlow is not legal for State --> State, Line:47
```

The reason I want to update is that I want to add a Stereotype to one of my connectors. 
I have sorted out a Specific EA.Element via SQL Quierie searching for 1 GUID.

```
"SELECT * FROM t_object WHERE ea_guid='<Some specific GUID>'"
```

From this Element I have selected the only connector that is a selftransition. 
If i understand correctly i have to set the selftransition tag, and then update the connector. But when i update, the Error message above is shown.

My code:

```
if(element.Elements.Count!=0)//element is Propably a comp state or Statemachine
    {   
        connectors = element.Connectors; 
        for(var j = 0; j<connectors.Count; j++)
        {
            connector = connectors.GetAt(j);
            if(connector.ClientID == connector.SupplierID)
            {
                tempElement = element;
                connector.Stereotype="New Stereotype";
                connector.Update();

            }   
        }       
    }
```

The Red Transition in the picture is the Transition that throws the error.

[image]

What does the Error mean and why cant i update the connector? 
If you have other suggestions how to add a stereotype to a connector i would gladly apreciate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems to be a bug, since StateFlow seems like a legitimate connector type between two States.

You can try unchecking the strict connector syntax setting in the options
[image]

If you still have this issue in the latest version then you can [report](http://www.sparxsystems.com/support/bug_report.html) it as a bug

If nothing helps you can always try to go around the API and to the database directly.
Try something like

```
Repository.Execute("update t_connector set stereotype = 'MyStereo' where connector_ID = 1234");
```

Replacing `1234` by the actual connector_ID of course.